# How to find the common group to which given candidates belong to

Tags: c++

Consider the following table below:

```
User ID       Group
1              G1, G2
2              G2, G4
3              G1, G3
4              G2, G3
5              G1
```

What is the quickest possible way to identify the common group for given users, say 1, 3 and 5? I am trying to implement this in C++.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pick one user (of those you are checking), go through groups 1 by 1 asking if others are in that group.

pick a user
    for (group = pick_1st_from_grp; group!=0; group=next_group) {
        are others members of this group?
        if all of them then this one is common
        else this one isnt common
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intersection of set recursively:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection